# SQL Server - Conditional Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, self-join

I have table as below:

**CallDetails**

| Caller | Receiver | StartedAt | StartedTimestamp | LastModifiedTimestamp | Outcome | Direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 91919 | 13.39 | 1636342600 | 1636342601 | Missed | Inbound |
| 111111 | 91919 | 15.40 | 1636342828 | 1636343128 | Missed | Inbound |
| 91919 | 111111 | 19.45 | 1636400728 | 1636401028 | Answered | Outbound |
| 222222 | 91919 | 20.50 | 1636404628 | 1636405000 | Missed | Inbound |

Expected output:

**MissedCallDetails**

| Caller | Receiver | MissedCallAt | CalledBackAt | IsContactedAgain | AnsweredMissedCall(In minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 91919 | 15.40 | 19.45 | YES | 245 |
| 222222 | 91919 | 20.50 |  | NO |  |

The 2 major conditions to union are as below:

1. When there is a returned call from the receiver to the same caller - it should considered `IsContactedAgain = YES`
2. When call is not returned back after the `LastModifiedTimestamp` to the caller

I need a union of missed calls which are `answered` and `unanswered`.

So far, I have come up with below:

```
SELECT
    m.StartedAt AS MissedCallAt
    , r.StartedAt AS CalledBackAt
    , 'Y' AS IsContactedAgain
    , DATEDIFF(mi, m.StartedAt, r.StartedAt) AS 'CalledIn(Minutes)'
FROM 
    CallDetails m, CallDetails r
WHERE 
    CONVERT(char(10), M.StartedAt,126) = DATEADD(Day, -1, CAST( GETDATE() AS Date)) 
    AND m.UserId IS NULL 
    AND m.Outcome = 'Missed call'
    AND r.Recipient = m.Caller
    AND r.StartedTimestamp > m.LastModifiedTimestamp
    AND r.Direction = 'Outbound'
ORDER BY 
    m.StartedAt, r.StartedAt
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I don't fully uderstand the logic, yet. You are looking for missed inbound calls, yes? But you are suppressing the call at 13.39. Is this because 111111 called 91919 again? So, you are looking for the *latest* missed inbound call per caller and callee? And for these calls you check whether there is a matching outbound call. If so, you mention the callback time in CalledBackAt and redundantly set IsContactedAgain = YES. Correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes and added to that I need to display IsContactedAgain = NO if that missed call was never got a call back.

Answer (score 1):

A left join can be useful here to include the missed calls without callback.

```
SELECT m.StartedAt AS MissedCallAt
, r.StartedAt AS CalledBackAt
, CASE WHEN r.StartedAt IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS IsContactedAgain
, DATEDIFF(minute, m.StartedAt, r.StartedAt) AS [CalledIn(Minutes)] 
FROM CallDetails m
LEFT JOIN CallDetails r 
  ON r.Direction = 'Outbound'
 AND r.Recipient = m.Caller
 AND r.Caller = m.Recipient
 AND r.StartedTimestamp > m.LastModifiedTimestamp
WHERE m.Direction = 'Inbound' 
  AND m.Outcome = 'Missed call'
  AND m.StartedAt > DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', DATEADD(Day, -1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)))
ORDER BY m.StartedAt, r.StartedAt
```

Comment: This way it is always setting `IsContactedAgain` to `NO`

Comment: @PratikSoni It's a LEFT join, so r.StartedAt is only null when there was no match.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with looking at the *latest* missed inbound calls per caller and callee.

Then, there should be only one callback it seems, but I'd write my query such that it can deal with multiple callbacks. Say, they call back, then see that they missed explaining a detail and call back the next day again. For this case we must decide whether to take the first callback time or the last one. A lateral join (`OUTER APPLY`) is a good way to deal with such situation.

```
with latest_missed as
(
  select top(1) with ties *
  from calldetails
  where direction = 'Inbound' and outcome = 'Missed'
  order by rank() over (partition by caller, receiver order by startedat desc)
)
select
  lm.caller,
  lm.receiver,
  lm.startedat as missed_call_at,
  callback.startedat as called_back_at,
  case when callback.startedat is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as is_contacted_again,
  datediff(minute, lm.startedat, callback.startedat) as answered_missed_call_in_minutes
from latest_missed lm
outer apply
(
  select top(1) *
  from calldetails cd
  where cd.caller = lm.receiver
    and cd.receiver = lm.caller
    and cd.startedat > lm.startedat
    and cd.direction = 'Outbound'
    order by cd.startedat desc
) callback
order by lm.caller, lm.receiver;
```

You may also want to consider how to treat outbound callbacks that are not 'Answered', but failed for some reason.